# How to update Kivy interface continuously with API response?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to do a basic system that can take the frame from webcam and send it to Azure Face API for emotion recognition and show the result on Kivy interface on my mac.

I have tried:

1 - write kivy classes `mytest` and `MyApp` inside while loop but the interface stuck due to the internal loop of kivy.

2- calling the `result_print` function inside the loop like this:

```
mytest().result_print(max_emotion, max_value)
```

but I got an error that the class is not defined.

3- trying the clock function from Kivy but after reading the documentation and previous question, I didn't get it where I have to write the function. I tried to write it inside the loop but also I got an error that the function is not defined.

btw, this is my first question on StackOverflow and I just began learning about OOP and kivy 3 days ago.

This is my full code blocks and hope to find someone can help on how to compile them.

```
#import ...    

# subscription key value
    subscription_key = "12345"
    assert subscription_key

    # endpoint URL
    face_api_url = 'https://emotion-recognition-project.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect'

    # headers
    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key, 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}

    # parameters
    params = {
        'returnFaceId': 'true',
        'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
        'returnFaceAttributes': 'emotion',
    }
    # Webcam
    cap = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()
    count = 0

    while True:

        # read the frame
        frame = cap.read()

        # convert to gray
        gray =cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # write the image
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('REST_API_test/images', "frame{:d}.jpg".format(count)), gray)  # save frame as JPEG file

        image_path = "REST_API_test/images/frame{:d}.jpg".format(count)
        image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()

        # send the image to API
        response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data = image_data )
        # response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, json={"url": image_url})
        result = response.json()
        if len(result) > 0:
            print(len(result))

            # find the max emotion with max value
            emotion = result[0]["faceAttributes"]["emotion"]
            max_value = max(emotion.values())
            max_emotion = max(emotion, key = emotion.get)
            print("The emotion is",max_emotion, "{:.0%}".format(max_value))
            Clock.schedule_interval(partial(result_print, max_emotion ,max_value), 1)


        # remove the frame
        os.remove("REST_API_test/images/frame{:d}.jpg".format(count))
        count += 1



    class mytest(GridLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(mytest, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            self.key = max_emotion
            self.value = max_value

        def result_print(self, key, value):
            key = self.key
            value = self.value
            self.add_widget(Label(text = key, pos = (400,200)))
            self.add_widget(Label(text = "{:.0%}".format(value), pos = (700,200)))


    class MyApp(App):
      def build(self):
          return mytest()

    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should put the code that accesses the webcam in a separate thread, and then call `Clock.schedule_once()` to do the Kivy interface update. Something like this:

```
#import ...
import threading


class mytest(GridLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(mytest, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            self.key = max_emotion
            self.value = max_value

        # need a `dt` argument (added by Clock.schedule_once)
        def result_print(self, key, value, dt):
            key = self.key
            value = self.value
            self.add_widget(Label(text = key, pos = (400,200)))
            self.add_widget(Label(text = "{:.0%}".format(value), pos = (700,200)))

        def do_updates(self):
            # subscription key value
            subscription_key = "12345"
            assert subscription_key

            # endpoint URL
            face_api_url = 'https://emotion-recognition-project.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect'

            # headers
            headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key, 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}

            # parameters
            params = {
                'returnFaceId': 'true',
                'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
                'returnFaceAttributes': 'emotion',
            }
            # Webcam
            cap = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()
            count = 0

            while True:

                # read the frame
                frame = cap.read()

                # convert to gray
                gray =cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                # write the image
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('REST_API_test/images', "frame{:d}.jpg".format(count)), gray)  # save frame as JPEG file

                image_path = "REST_API_test/images/frame{:d}.jpg".format(count)
                image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()

                # send the image to API
                response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data = image_data )
                # response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, json={"url": image_url})
                result = response.json()
                if len(result) > 0:
                    print(len(result))

                    # find the max emotion with max value
                    emotion = result[0]["faceAttributes"]["emotion"]
                    max_value = max(emotion.values())
                    max_emotion = max(emotion, key = emotion.get)
                    print("The emotion is",max_emotion, "{:.0%}".format(max_value))

                    # schedule update for next frame (leave out the timeout parameter)
                    Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.result_print, max_emotion ,max_value))


                # remove the frame
                os.remove("REST_API_test/images/frame{:d}.jpg".format(count))
                count += 1


    class MyApp(App):
      def build(self):
          theRoot = mytest()

          # start the update thread
          threading.Thread(target=theRoot.do_updates, daemon=True).start()

          return theRoot

    MyApp().run()
```

I haven't tested this, but I think this approach should work.

Comment: Thanks, your answer lead me to the solution. Besides of it, I have initialized the `max_emotion` and `max_value` variables at the beginning and make them global inside `do_updates` function. Also, I have assigned their values to `key` and `value` inside `result_print`. But now I have another problem which is printing the result above each other, that's mean when it updates the GUI does not remove the old result and print the new one. Do you know another layout can do that? I have read about `Screen` and `BoxLayout` but no solutions.

Comment: There is no `Layout` that will remove `Labels` without your direction. There is no way for the `Layout` to know what you want removed.  The typical way to handle this is would be to create your two `Labels` in the `mytest.__init__()` method (keeping a reference to those `Labels`), then the `result_print()` method just changes the `text` attribute of those two `Labels`.